# append text from div loaded from script element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some `div`'s dynamically loaded with javascript and I want to get the `text` from those `div`'s and `append` them into an existing div.

So, here's my code :

```
var firstoption  = jQuery( ".myo-poll-bar.firstoption"  ).text();
var secondoption = jQuery( ".myo-poll-bar.secondoption" ).text();

jQuery( ".votefilters span a:first" ).html( firstoption  );
jQuery( ".votefilters span a:last"  ).html( secondoption );
```

I know that there is an  `.append()` method  but I don't know how can I use it in this code.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstoption = jQuery( ".myo-poll-bar.firstoption" ).text();
var secondoption = jQuery( ".myo-poll-bar.secondoption" ).text();

var curr_text = jQuery( ".votefilters span a:first" ).text();
var curr_text2 = jQuery( ".votefilters span a:last" ).text();

jQuery( ".votefilters span a:first" ).html( curr_text  + firstoption );
jQuery( ".votefilters span a:last" ).html( curr_text2  + secondoption );
```

You can assign the object result to some variables so you don't have to traverse the dom twice to get the same object

Answer (score 1):

Using `multi-condition` in one selector is not a good practice.

For higher performance,
if `.firstoption` is enough, do not use `.myo-poll-bar.firstoption`

and split

```
jQuery( ".votefilters span a:first" )
```

to

```
jQuery(".votefilters").find("span").find("a:first")
```

All:

```
var firstoption  = jQuery( ".myo-poll-bar.firstoption"  ).text();
var secondoption = jQuery( ".myo-poll-bar.secondoption" ).text();

jQuery(".votefilters").find("span").find("a:first").append(firstoption);
jQuery(".votefilters").find("span").find("a:last" ).append(secondoption);
```

Comment: Why is a multi-condition selector "bad practice"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(firstoption).appendTo('.votefilters span a:first');
$(secondoption).appendTo('.votefilters span a:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$( ".votefilters span a:first" ).append( document.createTextNode( $( ".myo-poll-bar.firstoption" ).text() ) );
$( ".votefilters span a:last" ).append( document.createTextNode( $( ".myo-poll-bar.secondoption" ).text() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice:

```
var $first = jQuery( ".votefilters span a:first" );
var $last = jQuery( ".votefilters span a:last" );

$first.text(  $first.text() + firstoption );
$last.text( $last.text() + secondoption );
```